# Would this "get url" php code work on an IIS server?

Tags: php, iis

I use this PHP code on an apache server and it works fine:

```
$actual_link = "http" . (($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']==443) ? "s://" : "://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Now my question is if this would equally work on an IIS server. I've read that there are differences between them when using PHP so I would just like to be sure.

Thanks for your feedback :).

Comment: Why haven't you spent some time trying it?

Comment: I've read the best way to check is to try.

Comment: True but I don't feel like installing a local server just for this one sentence. It would take you guys just a second to read it whereas I will need to spend 30 minutes setting things up.

Comment: 30 minutes? Wow, I spend that much time sometimes *answering* these types of questions. Neat trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']==443`. Instead check if `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` equals 'on'.

Comment: @SnippetSpace One other thing, don't forget to include the port. It's possible to run a webserver on any port, and if you do you want your link to still work.